# Opening .FSD files

Tags: security, usb-storage

How do I open a file with a FSD extension on a Sony Micro Vault USB drive?

Receive an error message suggesting to look for a solution on line. This merely presents a number of vendors wishing to sell a fix which modifies the registry without any explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An .FSD could be from many programs, so you could try with these if you can get a copy of the software.
Some of them are:

- A COCO_COFE.Document from the [CAPE-OPEN Flowsheet Environment](http://www.amsterchem.com/coco.html)
- A [FacetWin](http://www.facetcorp.com/fw_overview.html) Backup File Set
- A Sheet (Document) by [Leaf Twenty-Five](http://www.leaf25.com/) - website currently empty

For more candidates, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=fsd+extension).

Did you open the file in a text editor or hex editor (don't save!) to look at its contents? That might also give clues about its origin.
Also, where did the file or USB come from? Please edit your question with that info.